# setting page tab image with graph api?

Tags: api, graph, facebook-apps

I can't find any field name to set the "page tab image" (as in the basic app settings) for an app through the graph api?

I know you can set a custom image for the app for each page using the api, but isn't it possible to set a standard page tab image for the app using the api?

Answer (score -1):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs:

> You can update an installed profile_tab for a page by issuing an HTTP POST request to /PAGE_ID/tabs/TAB_ID with Page Access Token and the following parameters:

Use parameters `custom_image_url` or `custom_image` to update the custom icon for a page tab.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you misunderstood what I want (my mistake - lousy explanation in my original post): I know I can set it "custom" for each page, but I'd like to set a standard tab image for the app itself, the same way you can do "manually" in the basic app settings, but this still doesn't seem to be possible?